# How these circles are congruent?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles, recreational-mathematics, sangaku

Here is a problem involving curvilinear incircles and mixtilinear incircles.

> [image]
>
> Let a triangle$\triangle$$ABC$ have circumcircle $\gamma$.It's A-Excircle tangency point at side$BC$ is $D$ Let $\gamma_1$ be the circle tangent to $AD$,$BD$,$\gamma$ also $\gamma_2$ is the circle tangent to $AD$,$CD$,and$\gamma$.prove that $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are congruent.

I have tried to prove the converse of the problem.

I drew two congruent circles on the same side of $BC$,$\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ tangent to $\gamma$ and $BC$.Let the tangency points of $\gamma$ and $\gamma_1$ are $\alpha_1$ and the tangency point of $\gamma_2$ and $\gamma$ be  $\alpha_2$.Let the tangents of $\gamma$ at $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ intersect at point $M$.Invert around the circle centered at $M$ and orthogonal to $\gamma$.Then I got stuck.

I have thought of another approach .according to Thebault's theorem,$P$,$I$,$Q$ are collinear where $P$,$Q$,$I$ are the centers of $\gamma_1$,$\gamma_2$and the incircle of $\triangle$ABC. Then I tried to prove the congruency of the incircle and $\gamma_1$ also The congruency of the incircle and $\gamma_2$.Also note that,$\angle$$BAD$=$\angle$$CAK$.where
$K$ is the tangency point of $\gamma$ and the A-mixtilinear circle of $\triangle$$ABC$.

I have tried two-approach but failed to go any further. Can someone help me?

Comment: This seems to be a revision of [a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4267329/409) of yours. Deleting and re-posting is not the appropriate way to bring more attention to a question. Rather, you should edit the question (for instance, adding your work, as you did here) to improve its quality. An edited question is "bumped" to the top of the unanswered queue, so you get that benefit of a re-post without causing confusion over deleted or duplicate questions. With enough reputation, you can also offer a bounty. ... There's no harm done here, but keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: Also, please be patient when seeking an answer. (Note that commenting an additional plea for help has no effect in calling attention to the question.) People visit Math.SE in their free time, which may-or-may-not align with your personal schedule.

Comment: @Blue, you are right.

Comment: Thanks you Blue.

Comment: See Fig. 1 p. 21 of [this document](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.02593.pdf) and the accompanying text.

Comment: Sorry not Fig. 1 but Fig. 18

Comment: @Jean Marie, Thank you.

Comment: But in fact, I thought at first we were in the same case, but in fact it looks only a similar case.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, this is proven in Theorem 4.5 of [Rabinowitz, *Relationships Between Circles Inscribed in Triangles and Related Curvilinear Triangles*](https://sangaku-journal.com/2020/SJM_2020_9-27_Rabinowitz.pdf).

That proof refers to Theorem 3.4 in [Rabinowitz, *More Relationships Between Six Circles*](https://sangaku-journal.com/2019/SJM_2019_106-118_Rabinowitz.pdf), which I mention because the link in the first paper is broken.